# How to get topN elements from this dict with list values?

Tags: python

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tag_dict = {'a':[('mary', 0.99, 'f'), ('tom', 0.87), 'm'],
            'b':[('jack', 0.43, 'm')],
            'c':[('martin', 0.987, 'm'), ('alice', 0.973, 'f')]}
```

I want to get a new defaultdict which contains top 3 elements sorted by the float number in each element. So for the example above, the result would be:

```
top3_dict = {'a':[('mary', 0.99, 'f')],
             'c':[('martin', 0.987, 'm'), ('alice', 0.973, 'f')]}
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Edit:

My actual question is a little more complicated. There are cases in which the original dict size is less than 3, so in that case the correct way to specify the problem is that:

```
Get up to topN elements sorted by the float number, if the elements are less n, just get all elements sorted order.
```

Comment: Luckily mary didn't have a value of 0.98 cause the sort order would have been ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten the structure out and store the outside key with the pairs. Then sort this, take the top three items and make the dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

sorted_items = sorted(
    [(k, item) for k,v in tag_dict.items() 
     for item in v], 
    key=lambda p: p[1][1], reverse=True)

for k, v in sorted_items[:3]:
    result[k].append(v)
```

Result will be:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'a': [('mary', 0.99, 'f')],
             'c': [('martin', 0.987, 'm'), ('alice', 0.973, 'f')]})
```

Above `sorted_items` will look like:

```
[('a', ('mary', 0.99, 'f')),
 ('c', ('martin', 0.987, 'm')) 
 ...
]
```

at which point making a new dict is simple.

Edit:

My actual question is a little more complicated. There are cases in which the original dict size is less than 3, so in that case the correct way to specify the problem is that:

```
Get up to topN elements sorted by the float number, if the elements are less n, just get all elements sorted order.
```

Comment: Let me test it. It seems very smart!

Comment: Please seem my addition. Sorry for the update.

Comment: I think the answer is the same.

Comment: @marlon, yes,  this should work fine even it the original input is smaller since it's just taking a slice of the list. If you changed the input above such that there were only two items, you would get those two items back.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = []
tag_dict = {'a':[('mary', 0.99, 'f'), ('tom', 0.87,'m') ],
            'b':[('jack', 0.43, 'm')],
            'c':[('martin', 0.987, 'm'), ('alice', 0.973, 'f')]}

for k,v in tag_dict.items():
    for entry in v:
        data.append((k,*entry))
data = sorted(data,key = lambda x: x[2],reverse=True)
result = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(0,3):
    result[data[i][0]].append(data[i][1:])
print(result)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [('mary', 0.99, 'f')], 'c': [('martin', 0.987, 'm'), ('alice', 0.973, 'f')]})
```

Comment: Thanks. The first answer is simpler.